# How to get a route without the action in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want my route to look like:

```
/product/123
```

I have an action GET but I don't want that in the URL, it is currently:

```
/product/get/123
```

How to get this?

Global.asax.cs

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" }
        );    
}
```

Comment: Show us how you have your route set up.

Comment: @Amy I added my route config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Route attribute to define your path like this:

```
[Route("product")]
public class ProductController {

    [Route("{productId}"]
    public ActionResult Get(int productId) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Which provides you the full route definition for "/product/{productId}" which is "/product/123" in your case. More details there: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in routes.MapRoute before the default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Product",
    url: "Product/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "product", action = "get"}
```

Comment: how do you do this with the new 3.0 routing stuff?